# how to cancel callback if no response arrived

Tags: node.js

how to cancel callback if no response arrived 
example

```
m.send(params, function(msg) {
    // msg will not arrive sometimes
})
```

i tried 
[In node.js if no response is received from an http request, how do you know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872833/in-node-js-if-no-response-is-received-from-an-http-request-how-do-you-know)

abort function not exist

Comment: What is `m` in your example?

Comment: Please show more relevant code so we can see what `m` is and what the overall context is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your callback function if the status code is 204 then it will be no response.